# Why camel need `+` sign in cron expression?

Tags: cron, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I was reading one of the article from Camel Website. http://camel.apache.org/quartz.html

and i am wondering why camel need `+` sign in cron expression? Previously also i have used cron expression but i don't remember using + signs.

`from("quartz://myGroup/myTimerName?cron=0+0/5+12-18+?+*+MON-FRI").to("activemq:Totally.Rocks");`

Comment: Hi! It's because the string is a URI and spaces need to be replaced by `+` in a URL/URI. However, Camel is somewhat inconsistent in this, as if you use the SQL component, you can use spaces anyway and it just handles it internally somehow.

Comment: Yeah it was how the quartz component was designed so many years ago. Maybe today we should consider allowing to use a space as well. If so you are welcome to log a JIRA